# comparing two fields in mysql -indexes?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I'm fairly certain I know the answer to this, but any ideas would be extremely helpful...

First of all, this is MySQL 5.1.32-community.  I have a large table (millions of rows, can't reduce the size - that is the reduced size) and the pertinent fields are two datetime fields.  We'll call it date1 and date2.  I need to run a select query that returns all rows (a actually UUID varchar(40) where date1 > date2.

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE date1 > date2;
```

It takes too long to run (2 minutes'ish).  Indexes on the dates themselves obviously do nothing.  Short of storing the difference between the two dates and indexing that - any methods to decrease the query time?  This seems like such a basic question, but I always wonder if maybe I'm just missing something...

Comment: What's wrong with storing the difference?  That would be my solution.

Comment: Because I only mentioned 2 dates, but the table actually has about 50, each of which might need to be compared to another.  Storing the difference of every possible date just isn't going to fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run a count to see if there just is really so much data being returned that it will take that long to return it all?

```
select count(ID) from table1 WHERE date1 > date2;
```

The query seems simple enough and your data volume might just be the problem.

Comment: There is a time difference - shaves about 10-20 seconds off.  I have several dates to compare against each other so I hate to have to store the difference and index that, but I think that's what I'll just have to do.  The DB writes once and reads all day - read speed is critical.

Answer (score 0):

i'm trying to find the answer my self.

but I 've a clue : index on function.

I've used it on Oracle Dbs.

but seams MySQL lacks the support :

[Is it possible to have function-based index in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595037/is-it-possible-to-have-function-based-index-in-mysql)