# Rails: ActiveRecord db sort operation case insensitive

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to learn rails [by following the SAAS course in coursera] and working with simple Movie table using ActiveRecord.

I want to display all movies with title sorted. I would like it to be sorted case insensitively.

I tried doing it this way:

```
Movie.all(:conditions => ["lower(title) = ?", title.downcase],:order => "title DESC")
=>undefined local variable or method `title' for #<MoviesController:0xb4da9a8>
```

I think it doesnt recognise lower(title) .

Is this the best way to achieve case insesisitve sort ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `where` and not `all`

```
Movie.where("lower(title) = ?", title.downcase).order("title DESC")
```

Don't really understand the sort though. Here you'll get all movies with lower title equalling to `title.downcase`. Everything is equal, how could you sort it by `title desc` ?

To sort reverse-alphabetically all movies by lowercase title :

```
Movie.order("lower(title) DESC").all
```

Comment: In Rails 6 this won't be allowed anymore, make sure to wrap any SQL like these in Arel.sql() (https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/310c3a8f2d043f3d00d3f703052a1e160430a2c2)

Answer (score 9):

You have to do this:

```
Movie.order("lower(title) DESC").all
```

Answer (score 6):

A more robust solution is to use arel nodes. I'd recommend defining a couple scopes on the `Movie` model:

```
scope :order_by_title, -> {
  order(arel_table['title'].lower.desc)
}

scope :for_title, (title)-> {
  where(arel_table['title'].lower.eq title.downcase)
}
```

and then call `Movie.for_title(title).order_by_title`

The advantage over other answers listed is that `.for_title` and `.order_by_title` won't break if you alias the `title` column or join to another table with a `title` column, and they are sql escaped.

Like rickypai [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11806024/8031815), if you don't have an index on the column, the database will be slow. However, it's bad (normal) form to copy your data and apply a transform to another column, because then one column can become out of sync with the other. Unfortunately, earlier versions of mysql didn't allow for many [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35380963/8031815) other than triggers. After 5.7.5 you can use virtual [generated columns](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/) to do this. Then in case insensitive cases you just use the generated column (which actually makes the ruby more straight forward).

Postgres has a bit more flexibility in this regard, and will let you make indexes on functions without having to reference a special column, or you can make the column a case insensitive column.

Comment: Thanks for this. An underrated answer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Having MySQL perform upper or lower case operation each time is quite expensive.

What I recommend is having a `title` column and a `title_lower` column. This way, you can easily display and sort with case insensitivity on the `title_lower` column without having MySQL perform upper or lower each time you sort.

Remember to index both or at least `title_lower`.