# Rails: ActiveRecord case-insensitive sort with dynamic table name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord, case-insensitive

[ [Rails: ActiveRecord db sort operation case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806004/rails-activerecord-db-sort-operation-case-insensitive) ] shows how to perform a case-insensitive sort with ActiveRecord.

> [Rails: ActiveRecord db sort operation case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806004/rails-activerecord-db-sort-operation-case-insensitive)
>
> ```
> Table.order("lower(column) DESC")
> ```

The code I am working with requires column name to be represented as a symbol so that ActiveRecord will automatically expand it to `"table"."column"`. This is required, because some queries contain a join statement with ambiguous column names.

> [GitLab CE: app/models/concerns/sortable.rb#L19-20](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/1fe7501b/app/models/concerns/sortable.rb#L19-20)
>
> ```
> scope :order_name_asc, -> { reorder(name: :asc) }
> scope :order_name_desc, -> { reorder(name: :desc) }
> ```

The table can't be hard coded into the method, because it is an abstract class used for several different tables.

**Is there a way to get the table name like ActiveRecord does?**

```
scope :order_name_asc, -> { reorder(%Q{LOWER("#{???}"."name") ASC}) }
scope :order_name_desc, -> { reorder(%Q{LOWER("#{???}"."name") DESC}) }
```

**Is there a way to use a symbolic column name and `LOWER` together and let ActiveRecord expand the table name?**

---

**Edit:** Fixed typo using backticks instead of double quotes in last example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord provides [`table_name`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-table_name) method for models.

So

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
User.table_name
#=> "users"
```

Thus, this can be used in scope:

```
scope :order_name_asc, -> { reorder(%Q{LOWER("#{table_name}"."name") ASC}) }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried that, but it causes the records to no longer be sorted by their name. I think there is something I don't fully understand. I will try to debug and determine what value `table_name` is being resolved to.

Comment: I found the issue. I was using backticks which performs a system call in ruby! I had ES6 on the brain. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JaredDeckard wow, my bad that i did not notice it. Good call!

Comment: I added an edit to the question. It would be greatly appreciated if you could update your answer for future travelers.

Comment: @JaredDeckard i'll be near laptop in about 30 mins and will make sure to edit, sure!