# Improving MySQL query performance with LEFT() function

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have function-based index in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595037/is-it-possible-to-have-function-based-index-in-mysql)

I have a table with a string field **s** and I want to run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE s = LEFT("färgkört", CHAR_LENGTH(s));
```

Its explanation clearly says that I am not using the index on that field:

```
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable      | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 766554 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

Is there any way to optimize a query like this?

Comment: Review: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595037/is-it-possible-to-have-function-based-index-in-mysql asked & answered.  MySQL doesn't support function based indexes. but it will support leading indexes for fixed length of characters. `create index name_first_five on cust_table (name(5));`

Comment: @MadMage Why do you want this?

Comment: The word "färgkört" is a compound, it is composed by "färg" and "kört". I have the latter two on mytable and I have to understand that "färgkört" is the compound of them. I run this query, sort by length descending and I find "färg", I remove (not in MySQL) it from the word and then I search for "kört". Any advices on alternatives on how to do this are welcome as well :-)

Comment: In this case you could use LOCATE() function, but it won't improve performance either.

Comment: If the words were separated by certain delimiter character (' ', ',', '.'), then you could use FULLTEXT searching.

Comment: @Devart I think the use of LOCATE lowers the performance, since I am looking for **s** that share the same _prefix_ with my word, I do not need to search elsewhere in the string... and unfortunately the words are not delimited (we could blame German or Swedish languages for this, but I think it's not fair to blame something because it's difficult to mechanize :-)).