# select datetime without specifying the time part?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a table like this:
[image]

I want to to do something like this:

```
select * from stat_tps Where min_date ='2013-06-12'
```

but the problem as you see the min_date is datetime format, so I have to provide the hh:mm:s part. I was wondering if there is any way that I can apply my query without specifying the hours-minutes and seconds?

thanks..

Comment: are you saying that it doesn't work? It should work.

Comment: unfortunately its not working ..

Comment: @jishi, it shouldn't work - the times are part of the evaluation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `DATE()` function:

```
SELECT * FROM stat_tps WHERE DATE(min_date) ='2013-06-12'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from stat_tps
Where date(min_date) = '2013-06-12'
```

But that won't take use of indexes if you have one on the `min_date` column. Better use

```
select * from stat_tps
Where min_date >= '2013-06-12'
and min_date < '2013-06-13'
```

Comment: Not possible [with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595037/is-it-possible-to-have-function-based-index-in-mysql)

Comment: Good point.  Sigh... one more missing feature to add to the list.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify a range, this will effecitvely use an index.

```
select * from stat_tps 
Where min_date BETWEEN '2013-06-12' AND DATE_ADD('2013-06-12',INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the `SUBSTR` function to chop off the time.

Comment: `select * from stat_tps Where SUBSTR(min_date,0,10) = '2013-06-12'`

Comment: I used the query you provided and its working perfect, but I had one problem and I wanted to put it here for others to benefit from it when using your answer... setting the length to zero didnt return anything so instead I set the length to 1 and it returned the desired results.  ` select * from stat_tps where substring(min_date,1,10)='2013-06-14' `

Comment: Yes, you're right, the [MYSQL documentation for SUBSTR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr) specifies that the first character of the string is at position 1.