# Faster way of selecting by date MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Right now I'm using:

```
MONTH(timestamp) = '7'AND YEAR(timestamp) = '2013'
```

To select by date but I've been told this is a very inefficient way of going about it, especially with a large amount of data. What is a faster way of obtaining the same results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Create an index on `timestamp` and then use:

```
where timestamp >= '2013-07-01' and timestamp < '2013-08-01'
```

This will use the index and perform well.

You create the index as:

```
create index <your table name>_timestamp on <your table name>(timestamp);
```

Comment: How do I create an index on timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it applies a function on every comparison. You can fix this with:

1. Not calling a function:

   ```
   where timestamp between date '2013-07-01' and date '2013-07-31'
   ```
2. Another way: create funcitonal index:

   ```
   create index myIndex on myTable(MONTH(timestamp),YEAR(timestamp));
   ```

For info: [Is it possible to have function-based index in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595037/is-it-possible-to-have-function-based-index-in-mysql)

Comment: MySQL supports neither functional indexes nor the `date` syntax you have suggested.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html - see documentation for literals if you think so. About indices - see link in the answer

Comment: . . I don't see what index prefixes on character columns have to do with functions such as `month()` and `year()` on a datetime column.  MySQL does not support the syntax that you have in the second part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Search for the range of dates, inclusive of 7/1 and exclusive of 8/1.

```
WHERE timestamp >= '2013-07-01' and timestamp < '2013-08-01'
```

Mysql helpfully automatically parses the date from YYYY-MM-DD foramt.