# Query using LEFT() function has bad performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I am using INNER JOIN and WHERE with LEFT function to match records by its first 8 chars.

```
INSERT INTO result SELECT id FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.zip=b.zip
WHERE LEFT(a.street,8)=LEFT(b.street,8)
```

Both `a.street` and `b.street` are indexed (partial index 8).

The query didn't finish in 24+ hours. I am wondering is there a problem with indexes or is there a more efficient way to perform this task

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause don't use indexes because the predicate is not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

Comment: @HamletHakobyan It seems *ridiculous* that `LEFT()` cannot be used intrinsically with indices (I can understand `RIGHT()` not being sargable) .. not that I expect too much optimization from MySQL these days, but I hope there would be more to it than that >_<

Comment: Translation of Hamlet's comment: since you're doing a string operation on what's in your WHERE clause, MySQL can't use any indexes you may have on that column since it has to perform that operation on *every single row in the table* to determine if the expression is true.

Comment: What are the indexes on the tables?  How large are the tables?

Comment: add fulltext indexes and use match against

Comment: Are the `zip` columns indexed? Add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for both tables.

Comment: Although it doesn't talk about LEFT or SUBSTRING(,0,) explicitly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595037/is-it-possible-to-have-function-based-index-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
INSERT INTO result
    SELECT id
    FROM tableA a INNER JOIN
         tableB b ON a.zip=b.zip
    WHERE LEFT(a.street,8)=LEFT(b.street,8);
```

MySQL is not smart enough to use a prefix index with this comparison.  It will use a prefix index for `like` and direct string comparisons.  If I assume that `id` is combine from `tableA`, then the following may perform better:

```
INSERT INTO result(id)
    SELECT id
    FROM tableA a
    WHERE exists (select 1
                  from tableB b
                  where a.zip = b.zip and
                        b.street like concat(left(a.street, 8), '%')
                 );
```

The index that you want is `tableB(zip, street(8))` or `tableB(zip, street)`.  This may use both components of the index.  In any case, it might get better performance even if it cannot use both sides of the index.

Comment: I will try this now. Does only tableB need index? And does it have to be multi column index? Thanks

Comment: TableB should have the composite index that I described in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Mysql won't use indexes for columns that have a function applied.

Other databases do allow function based indexes.

You could create a column with just the first 8 chars of a.street and b.street and index those and things will be quicker.