# select takes 20 seconds, delete still running @ 30minutes

Tags: mysql, sql

This select query takes about 20 seconds to complete.

```
 select Count(*)
   from products as bad_rows
   inner join (
   select pid, MAX(last_updated_date) as maxdate
      from products
       group by pid
         having count(*) > 1
      ) as good_rows on good_rows.pid= bad_rows.pid
        and good_rows.maxdate <> bad_rows.last_updated_date
        where bad_rows.available = 0
```

The delete on the other hand is still running after 30 minutes !

```
  delete bad_rows
     from products as bad_rows
      inner join (
       select pid, MAX(last_updated_date) as maxdate
          from products
           group by pid
             having count(*) > 1
          ) as good_rows on good_rows.pid= bad_rows.pid
            and good_rows.maxdate <> bad_rows.last_updated_date
            where bad_rows.available = 0
```

Why ?

Table Schema is as follows:

[image]

Explain for the select is as follows:

```
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                          |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  6253 |                                |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | bad_rows   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 34603 | Using where; Using join buffer |
|  2 | DERIVED     | products   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 34603 | Using temporary; Using filesort|
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------
```

Comment: What does the `EXPLAIN` plan look like for your query? How many rows?

Comment: How many indexes or function based on the table?  Deletes take longer when indexes exist due to the overhead of managing the indexes. or features like function based indexes... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595037/is-it-possible-to-have-function-based-index-in-mysql

Comment: 33000 rows. and 1  index (id). Trying `explain`

Comment: added the result of `Explain`

Answer (score 1):

ok so I just googled the results explain which hinted that my query could be slow because of not having indexes on pid. It didn't actually say that, but I just had a hunch from reading about the results of Explain. 
SO I added a index on pid and voila. Delete over in 1 minute!!

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com is an excellent introduction to how to use indexes.