# Why does MySQL drops my index when using DATE(`table`.`column`)

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization, innodb

I have a MySQL innodb table with a few columns.
one of them is named "dateCreated" which is a `DATETIME` column and it is indexed.

My query:

```
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
            `table1`
        WHERE 
            DATE(`dateCreated`) BETWEEN '2014-8-7' AND '2013-8-7'
```

MySQL for some reason refuses to use the index on the `dateCreated` column (even with `USE INDEX` or `FORCE INDEX`.

However, if I change the query to this:

```
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
            `table1`
        WHERE 
           `dateCreated` BETWEEN '2014-8-7' AND '2013-8-7'
```

**note the** `DATE(...)` **removal**

MySQL uses the index just fine.
I could manage without using the DATE() function, but this is just weird to me.

I understand that maybe MySQL indexes the full date and time and when searching only a part of it, it gets confused or something. But there must be a way to use a partial date (lets say `MONTH(...)` or `DATE(...)`) and still benefit from the indexed column and avoid the full table scan.

Any thoughts..?

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL can't use indexes on expressions like this. Because of that take care that you use functions only on the right side of a comparison operator.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595037/is-it-possible-to-have-function-based-index-in-mysql

Answer (score 1):

As you have observed once you apply a function to that field you destroy access to the index. So,

**It will help if you don't use between.** The rationale for applying the function to the data is so you can get the data to match the parameters. There are just 2 parameter dates and several hundred? thousand? million? rows of data. Why not reverse this, change the parameters to suit the data? (making it a "sargable" predicate)

```
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        `table1`
    WHERE 
         ( `dateCreated` >= '2013-08-07' AND `dateCreated` < '2014-08-07' )

    ;
```

- Note 2013-08-07 is used first, and this needs to be true if using between also. You will not get any results using between if the first date is younger than the second date.
- Also note that **exactly** 12 months of data is contained >= '2013-08-07' AND  < '2014-08-07', I presume this is what you are seeking.
- Using the combination of date(`dateCreated`) and between would include 1 too many days as all events during '2014-08-07' would be included. If you deliberately wanted one year and 1 day then add 1 day to the higher date i.e. so it would be < '2014-08-08'