# Is that a good practice to have a separate column with year of date in order to increase performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have such a table:

```
id | content | date
45 | "Lorem" | "2014-09-06"
56 | "Ipsum" | "2013-05-01"
```

The table has a lot of rows. Now I need to get different year values.

Statement:

```
SELECT YEAR(`date`) AS `year` FROM `news` GROUP BY `year` ORDER BY `date`
```

Unfortunately, this solution doesn't use `date` index.

My question is if it's a good practice to have a separate `year` column and set it before every insert/update and have an index on it?

Or is there a better solution?

Comment: is your date field varchar??

Comment: @LuisSiquot It's date column.

Comment: A [time-space tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff) if you ask me.

Comment: That's a weird query though. Same as `SELECT distinct(year(date)) FROM news`, isn't it? Doesn't seem to change a lot, maybe just cache the query result. And there is no reason why it should not use the date index...

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't use date index? How much is "a lot of rows"?

Comment: @Thilo I agree the result will be the same but I guess your solutions also doesn't use the `date` db index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [time-space tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff) if you ask me. In any case, to maintain normalization, you need to exclude the year from the date or never use it *for the purposes the year column exists for*.

A possible implementation is to use insert/update triggers as per [Is it possible to have function-based index in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595037/is-it-possible-to-have-function-based-index-in-mysql) . This shouldn't hurt performance much since news are likely to be added/updated much less frequently than read.

Comment: I agree. MySQL does neither support computed columns nor function-based indexes, so simply add a year column and have insert and update triggers care about it.