# MySQL Indices on Encrypted Field

Tags: mysql, indexing, aes

Is there a way to encrypt a field in a database and still have useful indexes on it?

For example, in the medical arena you need to encrypt patient information. If I do this on a patient name field, is there a way to still be able to have indexes on the decrypted value?

I'm thinking of using `AES_ENCRYPT()` on the field, but would really like to know if there is a trick to do the indexing on the decrypted value, not on the field's value (which would be encrypted).

Answer (score 0):

`AES_ENCRYPT()` and `AES_DECRYPT()` are functions. So the question in more general terms is:

> Can MySQL do indexing on functions?

As of `MySQL 5.6` the answer is no, although you can see this in other sql engines. For example `oracle` has done it since `8i` and `MS SQL` has done it since `2000`.

It looks like this might be possible in `Maria DB 5.2` (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/), which is a community version fork of MySQL.

References:

- [Is it possible to have function-based index in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595037/is-it-possible-to-have-function-based-index-in-mysql)
- http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/functions

Comment: If you think that AES functions will make the data more secure, keep in mind that the code is now the critical point of vulnerability, since the 'key' must be accessed in your code.