# How to create UPPER functional index in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

My JAVA code is using below select statement for fetching data. Col_1 is an index column but looking into  EXPLAIN, i am seeing that this select statement is not utilizing the index. If i remove UPPER function, it is utilizing index but I don't want to change my java code.

```
SELECT *FROM MY_TABLE WHERE UPPER(COL_1) = UPPER(input_value);
```

In ORACLE we can create functional index by using below statement but below index creation statement is not working in MySQL (8.0.12-commercial , innodb_version 8.0.12)

```
CREATE INDEX MY_INDEX ON MY_TABLE (UPPER(COL_1));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we create functional indexes in MySql for UPPERCASE and LOWERCASE functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006349/can-we-create-functional-indexes-in-mysql-for-uppercase-and-lowercase-functions)

Comment: Are you sure that you're using a case sensitive collation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL 8.0.13 allows [indexed expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-functional-key-parts).

```
create index upper_col1 on my_table ( (upper(col_1)) )
```

You can also solve this by ensuring all your values are normalized and keep them normalized with a trigger.

```
update my_table col_1 = upper(col_1);

create trigger normalize_col_1_on_insert
  before insert on my_table
  for each row
begin
  NEW.col_1 = upper(NEW.col_1)
end

create trigger normalize_col_1_on_update
  before update on my_table
  for each row
begin
  NEW.col_1 = upper(NEW.col_1)
end
```

Then be sure to also normalize your value.

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE COL_1 = UPPER(input_value);
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a valid reason for doing

```
UPPER(COL_1) = UPPER(input_value)
```

instead of doing

```
COL_1 = input_value
```

together with a case-folding `COLLATION` on `COL_1`.  That would let `=` take care of doing the 'right' thing.  There are probably cases where `UPPPER()` does the 'wrong' thing.  (I am thinking of things like the German `ß`.)

**Functional index**

This also works:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE
    ADD INDEX ucol_1 ((UPPER(COL_1)));
```

Be sure to use those extra parentheses.

(I verified it on a small test in Percona 8.0.16.)

Comment: I know that will resolve the issue, but it is not possible to change the JAVA code for me right now. That's why i was looking for a way forward

Comment: @RUAhmed - It is a simple `ALTER`; see my addition.

Comment: will it work on MySQL 8.0.12-commercial , innodb_version 8.0.12

Comment: @RUAhmed - The case-folding advice is valid since MySQL 4.1.  Functional indexes were added in 8.0.13.