# Haversine formula with Laravel relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, haversine

I've been working on calculation distances between two pairs of coordinates. The issue arises when you are working with a relation.

For example, I have a user table and an addresses table. Addresses table as a column `user_id` so each user has multiple addresses.

`UPDATE`
The latitude and the logitude are stored on a relation table called addresses and not on the users table.

Someones already come across this issue a few years ago, but it was never responded to.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/haversine-query-using-eloquent

[image]

When calculation the distance, this is what i have so far.

```
 $haversine = "(6371 * acos(cos(radians(cast(" . $coordinates->latitude . "as numeric))) 
    * cos(radians(latitude)) 
    * cos(radians(longitude) 
    - radians(cast(" . $coordinates->longitude . " as numeric))) 
    + sin(radians(cast(" . $coordinates->latitude . " as numeric))) 
    * sin(radians(latitude))))";


$users = $users->whereHas('addresses', function ($q) use ($radius, $haversine) {
    $q->selectRaw("{$haversine} AS distance")
        ->whereRaw("distance < ?", [$radius]);
    })->get();
```

But this throws an error

```
Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = character varying LINE 6: ...) AS distance from "addresses" where "users"."id" = "address... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. (
```

Ive tried playing around with the formula, and realized the the issue lies within the relation. Just cant put my finger on it. Has anyone come across this issue?

Thank you

Comment: This will be slow. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/40272394/1281385 for a speed improvement

Comment: @exussum that doesn't really answer my question

Comment: Hence a comment. Not an answer

Comment: I'm guessing the first concat had no space after  `. "as` needs the space before the word

Comment: @exussum good catch, but that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Why not just check the addresses, and then load the relevant user later?