# Could I cast VARCHAR to INT without broking INDEX?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, casting

Need to search through table `foo`

**foo** structure is

**id | something**

There is an `INDEX` for field `something`

I want to search BETWEEN AS INT:

```
SELECT CAST(something as INT) as something_int FROM foo foo_1
WHERE something_int > 1 AND something_int < 9999
```

In this case the INDEX would be used or be broken?

Comment: Have you used `EXPLAIN` to check?

Comment: If this is part of an EAV schema where `something` is a `VARCHAR` that sometimes represents a number, then my condolences; that is a flaw in EAV schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE some_varchar BETWEEN '1' AND '2000'  -- fast but probably incorrect
WHERE some_varchar BETWEEN 1 AND 2000      -- slow but correct
WHERE some_int BETWEEN '1' AND '2000'      -- fast
WHERE some_int BETWEEN 1 AND 2000          -- fast (same as previous)
```

What is happening?

- When comparing text to numeric, the text side is converted to numeric, and then numeric comparisons are performed.
- Text to text comparison does a string comparison; numeric to numeric does a numeric comparison.
- Above, I say "slow" meaning that no index can be used; "fast" if an index can be used.
- The "incorrect" one has the same problem as sorting a set of numbers in a `VARCHAR` and then wondering why the list is out of order:  1,10,11,...,19,2,20,...,29,3, ...
- `CAST()` is just an explicit version of the implicit conversion I am talking about here.
- `CAST('2000' TO INT)` is done "at compile time", so the Optimizer sees it as simply `2000` (numeric, no function call).
- `some_varchar >= 1` on the other hand, is turned into `CAST(some_varchar TO INT) >= 1` in the second example above.
- As a Rule of Thumb, "hiding a column in a function call prevents using an index.  See "sargable" in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

No, the index will not be used.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(something varchar(20) primary key) engine=myisam;
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('1|abc'), ('3456|def');

DESCRIBE SELECT * FROM foo WHERE CAST(something as INT) BETWEEN 1 AND 2000;
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | tt    | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 82      | NULL |    2 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+

DESCRIBE SELECT * FROM foo WHERE something BETWEEN '1' AND '2000';
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | tt    | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 82      | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

Notice how `possible_keys` is `NULL` for the first query (and `rows` found is `2`).

Note: this can happen even if the character set of the query doesn't match that of the index.

Create a separate INT index (e.g. using the [function index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595037/is-it-possible-to-have-function-based-index-in-mysql) syntax).

Comment: What about "index" vs "range"?  "Rows" is an estimate; you should not deduce anything from a minor difference such as "2" vs "1".  Technically the first one _does_ use the index, but as being more efficient than using the data.  (And there is a significant difference between MyISAM and InnoDB int this case.)  The second one _does_ use the index -- as indicated by "range" and "Primary"; it is a simple string comparison.  It is not the numeric comparison that was probably desired.  Function indexes are not available until recent versions.