# SQL: Is it possible to % CURDATE % in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I'm trying to use sql CURDATE(), in format "YYYY-MM-DD", to select items from yesterday  but time column is in "YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS" format.

Is it possible to put CURDATE between **% %**, something like in this example (which obviously doesn't work);
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE created_at LIKE % CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 day %`

Or if there is no syntax variation which makes use of curdate & also that works, do please recommend another way if there is any in sql bag of tricks.

Comment: Are you storing dates as text (e.g. `VARCHAR`)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález No. They are stored as datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use string functions as strings!  If you want yesterday, you can use:

```
where created_at >= current_date - interval 1 day and
      created_at < current_date
```

Plus, this can use an index.

Or, you can simplify this to:

```
where date(created_at) = current_date - interval 1 day
```

And this version does not use an index on `created_at`.

Comment: Note that the second option cannot use an index.

Comment: Second, more simplified option works and is best suited! Index is not of importance right now. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that MySQL finally supports [function based indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35380963/13508).